# java.io.FileNotFoundException: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied) while using flutter_pdfview package

Tags: flutter, dart, android-studio, pdf

As I have mentioned above I am facing this issue while viewing a pdf file already in my project asset folder but it gives me this error.

code:

```
var pdfPath='';

@override
void initState() {
  // TODO: implement initState
  super.initState();
  fromAsset('assets/pdf/read_book.pdf', 'book.pdf').then((f) {
    setState(() {
      pdfPath = f.path;
    });
  });  }
Future<File> fromAsset(String asset, String filename) async {
  Completer<File> completer = Completer();

  try {
    var dir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    File file = File("${dir.path}/$filename");
    var data = await rootBundle.load(asset);
    var bytes = data.buffer.asUint8List();
    await file.writeAsBytes(bytes, flush: true);
    completer.complete(file);
  } catch (e) {
    throw Exception('Error parsing asset file!');
  }

  return completer.future;
```

I just want to display a PDF file already in the project assets directory, any solution if possible?

Comment: Did you add the `pdf` directory in your pubspec.yaml?

Comment: Yes and also the file can be viewed through another package (syncfusion_flutter_pdfviewer: ^23.1.43) but it's very time-consuming